# What is on-die ECC?

Tags: memory, ecc

According to Crucial,

> Designed with on-die ECC (ODECC)8 at the component level for long-term stability, Crucial DDR5 is engineered to maintain the same reliability as the previous generation, even with the rigorous demands of next-gen computing.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking this up I found this

> A: **No. Crucial DDR5 Desktop Memory is non-ECC memory.** The ECC as it pertains to RDIMMs, LRDIMMs, ECC UDIMMs, and ECC SODIMMs is a function that requires additional DRAM at the module level so that platforms such as servers and workstations can correct for errors on individual modules (DIMMs). On-die ECC (ODECC), however, is a feature of the DDR5 component specification and should not be confused with the module-level ECC feature. Crucial DDR5 Desktop Memory is built with DDR5 components that include ODECC, however **these modules do not include the additional components necessary for system level ECC.**

You can read more about this [on the Wikipedia page for DDR5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR5_SDRAM#Features). Seems ECC protects the request anywhere en route to the CPU. And ODECC protects the request only on the RAM itself.

Comment: "*Seems ECC protects the request anywhere en route to the CPU*" -- Such blanket generalizations are incorrect for a code that has many possible applications. For instance HDDs use ECC, and that use of ECC is entirely self-contained to the drive. But your conclusion is simply incorrect. The data bus doesn't have the extra width for the ECC,, nor does the CPU have the time or logic to perform the check and correction. The memory ECC would be handled at the memory *module* level. "*RAM itself*" is ambiguous; you need to learn to distinguish between die or chip versus module.